# HTML Form into PHP: No such File or Directory

Tags: php, html, windows, apache, xampp

I googled a lot and even tried many solutions from this site, but none helped... I Even cutted my php File to a simple printf, but even that doesnt work. Here are both Files:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Tauschbörse</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta author="Andreas Köhler">
    <link rel=stylesheet href=login.css>
</head>
<body class="login"> 
    <h1 align="center" class="login"> Bitte tragen Sie Ihre Zugangsdaten ein</h1> 
    <form action="register2.php" method="GET" enctype="text/plain" name="RegisterForm"> 
        <table align="center" class="login"> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Benutzerkennung</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="txtUser" /></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Passwort</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="txtPassword" /></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Passwort wiederholen</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="txtPassword" /></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>E-Mail</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="txtPassword" /></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td><input type="submit" value="OK" /></td> 
                <td><input type="reset" value="Eingabe l&ouml;schen" /></td> 
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </form> 
</body>
```

and the new, cutted php File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>Registrieren</title>
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        printf("test");
    ?> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

But i always get this error, when i click on the ok button:
[image: No such File or directory]

The Problem is, both Files are in the same directory and it has to find my register2.php, because if not, i just get the following error:
[image: Object not found]

I have to code a big Project in the next 2 Months and in School i made it exactly like that on a Linux xampp and it works, but Windows literally doesnt seem to like it that way...

Comment: problem is `no such file or directory` in file `register2.php` i guess paths will be the problem here, also error 404 means that server cannot find what to process depending on request not that the include link is to nonexisting file !

Comment: But i get the error 404 only when i delete the File.
SO the Problem is IN register2.php? But how? There is literally nothing in it except an echo/printf

Comment: then maybe privileges, server don't have permissions to read

Comment: I found the Problem, it was cause of an "ö" in the directory name. I changed it to oe and now it works